# creating jar with look n feel library jars

Tags: java, executable-jar

in my java project i have look n feel jar files.

```
 try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackEyeLookAndFeel"); 


     } catch (Exception ex) { 
        }
```

so when i create jar file for my project  it produces jar and a lib folder containing those look n feel jars. when i copy both folders into new place it worked well

but when i copy only jar it opened in default look n feel way

is there any way to solve it

Comment: You have to copy the lib folder along with the jar files , because they are externally added jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.xml file--you may need to edit your build.xml file to merge those JAR files in your JAR.

```
    <!-- Change the value of this property to be the name of your JAR,
         minus the .jar extension. It should not have spaces.
         <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
    -->
    <property name="SOR.jar.name" value="MarsRoverViewer"/>


    <!-- don't edit below this line -->

    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

</target>
```